# Git Push to Amazon S3 for Deploying Assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, amazon-s3

Can you install git on Amazon and push assets (js, css, img) easily?  Something like Heroku but with assets and S3 would be awesome.

Some people seem to use JungleDisk to sync a local git directory to s3, but that's too bulky.  I tried installing [jgit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/) on a mac but to no avail, and that thing looks ancient.  Is there anything else or does this type of thing just not work?

I've tried most of the gems out there for heroku asset deployment/optimization, but they all either require you to host them on heroku, or to run a rake task, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [s3cmd --sync LOCAL s3://BUCKET/PREFIX](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) to accomplish this. It is best if each asset has a version number in its name. Otherwise you can have weird issues such as the browser caching version 1 of the CSS and using version 2 of the JavaScript, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: will that sync just the changes, so if I have 100 images and I change 1 locally, it will only upload that 1, like git.  Or does it upload everything again?

Comment: Normally Git stores the data in [loose object format](http://book.git-scm.com/7_how_git_stores_objects.html), which means that every version of every file is stored in its own file. If you change one byte in a 100 megabyte file git will write 100 megabyte for the one byte change. If you use "s3cmd sync" 100 megabytes will be send to Amazon. The above statement that only the differences are synced is only correct, if you tell git to use the packed objects format, which is not the default.

Comment: EDIT: This is now just `s3cmd sync ./ s3://Your-bucket`, no -- flag on the sync

Answer (score 1):

How about setting up an EC2 image, mounting the s3 image on there and setting up a bare git repository to push to on said S3 image?

Answer (score 1):

Tools recommend by other answers are out of date.

This one is up to date: https://github.com/schickling/git-s3

Answer (score 0):

See Jammit s3, it's a great solution (zip + cloud):

https://github.com/railsjedi/jammit-s3

Comment: the only thing with this is that it pushes everything every time.  so if you have a lot of images it takes a while.  if it could somehow figure out the diffs, them i'm in :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Jammit s3 is that you cannot manage versions of your files properly. It might take end users a while until they get the most update to date JS/CSS file.

You might find this useful, in case you use PHP for your application (otherwise this code can be adapted to your needs): https://github.com/SupersonicAds/git-hook-php-s3-files-revisions

Answer (score 0):

Jammit S3 didn't have the control I was looking for, so I wrote my own CLI script:

https://github.com/bradt/git-deploy-s3